# Estimate file space usage on a device (not in a directory)

Tags: disk-usage

I have two devices `/dev/sdc1` and `/dev/sdc3`.

`/dev/sdc1` is mounted on `/` and `/dev/sdc3` is mounted on `/home`.

The problem is that the device `sdc1` is full whereas `sdc3` has a lot of spare space. I want to determine where all that space on `sdc1` gone (I suspect installed packages. a lot of them).

I tried to use `du` (and `ncdu` which makes this info more visual) but it calculates size of the whole tree (`/home` is nested on `/`) and I want to know only what's filling one of my devices. Is there a way to do that?

To clarify: I need some way to calculate usage of a *device*, not just exclude some subdirectories (which may be applicable in my situation, but I believe it can be more complex than that)

Comment: Assuming Linux utilities: `du -hs * | sort -rh`.  You can drill it down from there.

Comment: Use also [df(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/df.1.html) in addition of `du`

Comment: @SatoKatsura You can't use `| sort` with `du -h`. The `-h` allows the unit to vary, so you can end up with a 10tb file/directory in the middle of couple a kb ones.

Comment: @Patrick: Newer versions of `sort` has a `-h` (which @SatoKatsura used) option to sort human readable numbers, exactly for this.

Comment: @Patrick Hence "assuming Linux utilities".  With POSIX utilities it would be something like `du -ks * | sort -rn`, but the output is less readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To limit to a single device you need the `-x` parameter of `du`

```
-x, --one-file-system
          skip directories on different file systems
```

A useful graphic front-end to du is `xdiskusage`.